# Do tablets support External HDDs?

Tags: external-hard-drive, tablet, microsoft-surface-pro

I have found different models of popular external HDDs sometimes not working with tablets such as Microsoft's Surface Pro.

The question of compatibility arises because of the power requirement for those external HDDs. Do the tablet devices have enough juice to power the external HDDs?

As far as I know, Microsoft no longer advertises the Surface Pro as a tablet and it is no longer based on Windows RT. Where does this place the Surface Pro on the type of devices? Laptop or Tablet?

P.S. Sorry about multiple questions, this is my first question here.

Comment: Anecdotal evidence: My Nexus 5 had enough juice to power an external HDD, so tablets certainly ought to.

Comment: Can they support external drives? Sure. *Do* they support external drives? It depends entirely on the manufacturer.